# Проблемы с веб камерой в Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, macos, virtualbox, web-camera

Здравствуйте, у меня на компьютере с Mac OS X есть виртуальная машина с Ubuntu. Когда я пытаюсь запустить там любое приложение, использующее встроенную веб камеру у меня появляются ошибки (вроде NoneType has not attribute ... при попытке считать кадр с video_capture в OpenCV) или черное окно с надписью "камера не найдена". При попытке прописать следующие команды в os x

```
VBoxManage controlvm "Ubuntu Linux" webcam attach
VBoxManage controlvm "Ubuntu Linux" webcam list
```

Я получаю следующую ошибку после выполнения первой строки

```
VBoxManage: error: Attach emulated USB webcam (VERR_PDM_NO_USBPROXY)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "WebcamAttach(path.raw(), settings.raw())" at line 1652 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
```

Если кто-нибудь раньше сталкивался с подобной проблемой – подскажите пожалуйста, что стоит делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: А екстеншн пак установлен? И если да - то той версии которой и виртуалбокс?